# Unable to merge xls file using tidyverse

Tags: r, merge, xls, readxl

I'm trying to merge some xls files in a path into one single file using tidyverse.

Getting this error: New names:

> - `` -> ...2
> - `` -> ...3
> - `` -> ...4
> - `` -> ...5
> - `` -> ...6
> - ... and 63 more problems
>
> Error:    filepath: D:\path\to\files\cersai_reverse_0112102018.xls   libxls error: Unable
>   to open file

Please advise.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <- dir("D:/path/to/files/", full.names = T) %>% map_df(read_excel)
```

Comment: check your file extension is  xls or xlsx.

Comment: i think you should use `read_xls` function

Comment: @RajithThennakoon It is xls.

Comment: @RajithThennakoon Added the gdata library for using read.xls. Got the following error: Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument

Comment: is your file open in excel and trying to read same time?

Comment: @RajithThennakoon No.

Comment: oh you having perl not found issue.you should have perl installed.                          
`prl <- "<perlpath>/perl.exe"
data <- read.xls(url_xls, prl)`